# How to pass a function in an ajax call from JQuery to a Node.JS server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Here is my code

```
let url = "/blabla";
let ajax_options = {
    data:{
        params_list:{
            sortFunction: (x, y) => parseFloat(x) - parseFloat(y);
        }
    }
};
$.ajax(url,ajax_options).then((res) => {
    //do something
});
```

But when I check the actual GET url that my browser has tried to load I get :

```
http://localhost/blabla?params_list[sortFunction]=NaN
```

How am I supposed to write the code to get it to pass the function definition properly ?

Comment: Since all data sent is string just wrap the function in quotes? Or are you trying to send the result from calling the function?

Comment: trying to send the definition of the function. Ideally even a function i have defined elsewhere in my code and passing it by name

Comment: use POST and try stringify it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save function reference to variable and use `Function#toString()` before it gets internally parsed by $.ajax

```js
const fn = (x, y) => parseFloat(x) - parseFloat(y),
      url = 'https://httpbin.org/get';

let ajax_options = { 
  data: {
    params_list: {
      sortFunction: fn.toString()
    }
  }
};

$.ajax(url, ajax_options).then(({args, url}) => {
  console.log('Response data ::', args);      
  console.log('URL used ::', url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note should propably also use `encodeURIComponent()` since it is a GET. Shouldn't be necessary if send as POST instead

Comment: You shouldn't call `encodeURIComponent. `$.ajax` does that automatically, so you would get double encoding.

Comment: @Barmar I would have thought so but note the actual url in log has spaces left in it. Maybe it's just really late and I'm not thinking straight

Comment: thks for the answer. And how would you get it back on the other end i.e the nodejs server ? so from string to function again ?

Comment: @chapo no simple way that would be secure. You could use `eval()` but that is also very dangerous with malicious input. Perhaps you should rethink this if you need to call that actual function server side. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes I ended up writing the function on the server and calling it by passing its name into the params.

Comment: will still validate your answr since it does what I asked

Comment: Yes. That approach sounds a lot smarter